# Get LOC count for classes and methods using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, lines-of-code

I have installed Jenkins for my projects. The automatic build and deployment is happening successfully.
I would like to get following data:

1. No. of classes with lines in the range 0-50
2. No. of classes with lines in the range 301-500
3. No. of classes with lines in the range 501-1000
4. No. of classes with lines > 1000 etc.

I'd like the same things for methods: Eg: No. of methods with lines in the range 0-50
How can I get this data?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use http://cloc.sourceforge.net/

You can then extract the data as SQL data import it in a H2 database (in-memory) to
group accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more than you need, but have you looked at Sonar?  (http://www.sonarsource.org/) It integrates with your build, and can provide the metrics you're looking for and a lot more besides.

Answer (score 0):

There are several other useful and easy to use tools:

- javancss: A Source Measurement Suite for Java http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/
- ckjm: Chidamber and Kemerer Java Metrics http://www.spinellis.gr/sw/ckjm/

Some relevant tools:

- classycle - http://classycle.sourceforge.net/
- jdepend - http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html

You can also use [XRadar](http://xradar.sourceforge.net) to aggregate all these report and get something called "Project health". XRadar also supports previously mentioned [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the issue is still relevant to you. The other responses do not address Jenkins. There are several plugins for Jenkins, such as http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/. After you install the plugin, you can retrieve code metrics via the Jenkins REST API.